# How can we pass different browser at once in robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
*** Variables ***

${BROWSER}          firefox
${URL}              http://url/
${Delay}            0
```

in my settings.txt file i have a variable named {BROWSER} AND  associate value as shown above it is firefox

but what i want is

```
*** Variables ***

@{BROWSERS}         firefox  chrome  IE  
${URL}              http://url/
${Delay}            0
```

something like above... so when i run test-suite first it will run in firefox and after completion of all testcases it will close firefox and will open chrome and run all the test cases again on chrome browser ..and so on after this it will run on IE

so how could we do this?

I don't want to do it manually (I mean by passing one by one or by editing txt file).
fully automatically.... once i run the test it will automatically test in all the browsers.

PS: this is in settings.txt file and i have two folders in which i have test.txt files. so there is the main problem ..i have to iterate these folders in a loop

```
|-- main.py
|-- settings.txt    //in this file i have browser variable (or Array)
|-- test1
|   |-- testl.txt
|   |-- test1_settings.txt  //this will contain all the variables and user defined keyword related to test1 and 
|-- test2
|   |-- test2.txt    
|   |-- test2_settings.txt  //same as test1
```

i run test cases like this
`$pybot test1 test2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see 2 ways to do it.

1) loop over your browser and call a keyword that do your test:

```
*** Variables ***
@{BROWSERS}          firefox  chrome  IE

*** test cases ***
test with several browser
    :FOR  ${browser}  IN   @{BROWSERS}
    \  log to console  call keyword that does your test with ${browser}
```

Here is what you get with this test:

```
[Mac]$ pybot .
Browser.Ts
==============================================================================
test with several browser                                             
call keyword that does your test with firefox
call keyword that does your test with chrome
call keyword that does your test with IE
test with several browser                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Browser.Ts                                                            | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

2) another way (which I prefer) is to keep your ${BROWSER} variable with a single value and call your test case several time with a new value for the variable that you give on the command line:

```
[Mac]$ pybot --variable BROWSER:firefox ts.txt
[Mac]$ pybot --variable BROWSER:chrome ts.txt
[Mac]$ pybot --variable BROWSER:ie ts.txt
```

Comment: solution 2 should work, no? That is the way I do that kind of thing and I am happy with it. I launch my tests with Jenkins and I have 1 job per configuration I want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've solved this problem by writing a simple script.

I Just wrote a program which will read the file settings.txt and find the line `@{BROWSER}          firefox  chrome  IE`
and then extract browsers name and store into a list . so this script will return a List something like this
['firefox', 'chrome', 'IE']

now instead of using single pybot command I'll use it in a Loop

```
for browser in browsers:
        call(['pybot','--variable'] +['BROWSER:%s'%browser] + test_args)
```

settings.txt file will contain two variable

```
${BROWSER}          firefox      #So default browser is firefox. you can leave it blank
@{BROWSERS}         firefox  chrome  IE
```