# How to run a single test case to multiple browser in robot framework

Tags: python, cross-browser, robotframework

Is this possible to execute cross browser testing robot framework - python with RIDE.

I am using RIDE, I was wondering run a test case at a single time in all browser like chrome, firefox, safari. I could able to run a test case as separately in all browser.

I tried Pabot library, but not able to identify where the list of the browser we can call?

Thanks.
Nall11

Comment: You can find answer in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965583/how-can-we-pass-different-browser-at-once-in-robotframework

Answer (score 2):

Place a list of browsers you want to execute your test case in a list and run the `for loop` for your test case

```
*** Variables ***
@{BROWSERS}          Chrome firefox chrome

*** test cases ***
test with several browsers
    :FOR  ${browser}  IN   @{BROWSERS}
    \  Step 1
    \  Step 2
```

so that your test case will run in all the browsers which you have listed in @{BROWSERS}. Your test script will be failed if it failed at any case(any browser)

Comment: Simple and effective.